# Enable paper-inputs when button is clicked (polymer 1.0)

Tags: javascript, html, json, polymer

I'm working on a project about a list of doctors and I'm using polymer 1.0.

For the doctor-list I use a vaadin-grid called **doctors-grid.html** where I'm getting the data from a JSON. When a doctor is double clicked, a modal dialog opens with the information about the selected doctor.
The content of the dialog is a separate component called **doctor-details.html**.

The information about the doctor is written in disabled paper-input fields.

I have a modify button in this dialog. When I click on this button, the text of the button changes to "Save".

**Now to my problem:**  Now I also want to **enable** these disabled paper-input fields when I click on the modify button, so I could change the information about the doctor. After I changed it I want to save the modified data back to the JSON and change the button again to "Modify" and disable all input-fields again.

**This is a part of my doctor-details.html**

```
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/paper-input/paper-input.html"/>
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/paper-input/paper-textarea.html"/>

<dom-module id="doctor-details">
  <template> 
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>Name</td>
          <td><paper-input label="{{doctordata.name}}" disabled></paper-input></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Forename</td>
          <td><paper-input label="{{doctordata.forename}}" disabled></paper-input></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
  </template>

  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'doctor-details',
      properties: {
        doctordata: {
          type: Object,
          value: null
        }
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

This is from the **doctors-grid.html**, where I click the button and the paper-inputs from the **doctor-details.html** should be enabled, so I can modify them. And in this function i also should **enable these inputfields**.

```
         onClick: function() {
          var button = this.$.msbutton;
          button.textContent = 'Save';

          var inputfields = [];
        //How can I save all paper-inputs in this array?
        //How can I enable all paper-inputs?
        }
```

[image]

I don't post the whole code directly here, because I think it's easier when you look at the whole project (and it would be too much code).
So I have a link to my dropbox: https://www.dropbox.com/s/crsrixs0nw6tvyy/WebContentEN.zip?dl=0

I googled and tried myself, but I always failed. I'm a beginner in polymer, so i would really appreciate it if someone can help me, because I really have no idea how to do this. Thanks!

Comment: I think you should isolate the immediate issue and post a minimal example here. Linking to entire project wont's attract good answers

Comment: Okay I edited my question with some more examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I save all paper-inputs in this array?

It's not a good idea to directly retrieve input fields from grid elements. You can control the `disabled` property with binding. On the inside you create a property in `doctor-details` and bind it to inputs.

```
<paper-input label="{{doctordata.name}}" 
             disabled="{{disabled}}></paper-input>

<script>
Polymer({ 
   is: 'doctor-details',
   properties: { disabled: Boolean }
});
</script>
```

On the outside add the same property and bind with each `doctor-details`.

```
<doctor-details disabled="{{editDisabled}}></doctor-details>

<script>
Polymer({ 
   is: 'doctor-grid',
   properties: { 
      editDisabled: {
         value: true
      }
   },

   onClick: function() {
        this.editDisabled = !this.editDisabled;
   }
});
</script>
```

> How can I enable all paper-inputs?

To sum up, you control all input through a single boolean property bound to your elements.

Also, I'd rather have two buttons to hide/show depending on `editDisabled` rather than change the title of a single button.